# Convergence of generic p-series

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the generic p-series:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{p}}$

Let the increment function be: $n= n+K$

where $K$ is some integer constant. For $K=1$ its simple p-series and that diverges for any $p<1$.

Can we have some integer value of $K$ beyond which the series converges for $p<1$. Specifically for $ 1/2 < p <1.$

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+K)^p}$ converges iff $p>1$ (regardless of $K$). Did you mean something else?

Comment: Ah it didn't sorry. The question is what if we consider every $K^{th}$ term for the values of $n$. Does the same constraint still hold true? or can we for some $K$ have the series converge even if $p<1$. I would thus rewrite the question as $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n*K)^p}$

Comment: Then it is $\displaystyle\frac{1}{K^p}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}$. With the same outcome.